# Alternative solutions for $\cos(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a function $f(x)=x+2\sin(x)$ and we are asked to find at which points the graph of $f$ has  Horizontal tangents.

How we solve is to find where $f'=0$.  So $$f' = 1+ 2\cos x = 0 \implies \cos x = -\frac 12$$ and from this, to determine the solution set.

I am familiar with unit circle and periodicity of $\sin,\cos$ functions so I found out that the solution set is $$x \in \left\{(2k+1)\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}:   k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

I know that is the usual way but is there any alternative solution -simpler if possible- to this problem? Especially for the people who does not the subject well?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x+2\sin x$ doesn't have any vertical asymptotes. Your reasoning makes little sense: solving the equation $f'(x)=0$ tells you where the tangent line to the graph is horizontal. What does this have to do with vertical asymptotes?

Comment: $f'(x) = 0$ tells you where you can expect to find maxima and minima (critical points), of the function.  See if you can create a set describing all local maxima, and another set which describes all local minima. (e.g., maxima at $\{2k+1)\pi + \frac \pi 3: k\in \mathbb Z\}$)

Comment: Still not quite right. You want to say “horizontal tangents”.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, I made a typo mistake, unfortunately. Vertical must be "horizontal". My bad.

Comment: If you are familiar with the unit circle, then draw it, and then plot all of the points on that circle where the value of the $x$ coordinate is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Afterwards, add multiples of $2\pi$ to those angles.

Answer (score 3):

$f′(x)=0$ tells you where you can expect to find local maxima and minima (critical points), of the function, which occur when the tangent line to the curve is horizontal.

You correctly found the derivative $f'(x) = 1 + 2\cos x$, and setting $f'=0$
you've solved for these $x$ quite well! Indeed, the solution set is given, as you found, by $$x \in \left\{(2k+1)\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}:   k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

So the horizontal tangent lines will be given by $$\left\{f(x): x \in \left\{(2k+1)\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}:   k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\right\}$$

Taking just one local maximum, when $x= \frac {2\pi}{3}$, we have the tangent line given by $$f\left(\frac {2\pi}3\right) = \frac{2\pi}{3} + \sqrt 3$$

We can compare the curve with one of its tangent lines:

[image]

Comment: There really isn't a simpler way to approach this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

One is 120. This can be found by noticing that $\cos(30)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos(x) = -\cos(x+90)$. Since $f(x) = \cos(x)$ has a period of 360, we can keep adding 360 to get solutions. Solutions are as follows: $\{\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{8\pi}{3},\frac{10\pi}{3}, \cdots\}$

Comment: You've only identified half the solutions.  $x \in \{ \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{10 \pi}{3}, \ldots, \}$

Comment: Sorry; that is what I meant to type.

Comment: The solution set is comprised of the union of the set you previously posted, and this set  refer to above.  So now you've posted the other half of the solutions.

Comment: My original solutions were for 0.5 not -0.5 like the question said.

Comment: $\cos (2\pi/3) = -\frac 12$.  Any angle terminating  in the second or third quadrant is going to have a negative value for cos.  In this case, for example, $\cos \frac{2\pi} 3 = \cos \frac {4\pi}3 = -\frac 12$.

Comment: Yeah. I made a mistake and thought that the period was 360 instead of 180. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm thinking that your answer has become more confusing than clarifying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55099/discussion-between-nairit-sarkar-and-amwhy).

Comment: Please see [this unit circle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/Unit_circle_angles_color.svg/300px-Unit_circle_angles_color.svg.png) where you can see where $\cos 2\pi/ 3$ occurs, and when $\cos 4\pi/3$ then again, add 2\pi to each of those values, and we get to more solutions....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tan half angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) substitution $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$  to get

$$ \left. \cos x = -\frac{1}{2} \right\} \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = \left. -\frac{1}{2} \right\} t = \pm \sqrt{3} $$

Then $$x = 2 \tan^{-1} t = \pm 2 \tan^{-1} \sqrt{3} = \pm 2 \frac{\pi}{3}$$

The periodicity means that you can add $k \pi$ angle to $x$ where $k=0,1\ldots \infty$

This is not a great application of the tan half angle method, but it is a different way to get the same result.

Here are the rules of the Weierstrass substitution as it is called sometimes:

> $$ \begin{align} t & =  \tan \frac{x}{2} \\ \sin x & = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \\ \cos x & = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \end{align} $$